# Can't use TimeDistributed with LSTM

Tags: python, keras

I try to use the TimeDistributed layer of Keras, but I have some issues.

Dataset shape:

Training Set: (800, 7, 231) with 7 being the timestep.

Training Labels: (800, 7)

Validation Set: (700, 7, 231)

Validation labels (700,7)

My goal is to do binary classification. I have information for seven successive day (with explain why 7 is my timestep). I also have the labels for the 7 successive days, **which I want to use in order to predict only the last day (the seventh day)**.

Below is my code:

```
from keras.layers import LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(120, input_shape=(final_dataset.shape[1], final_dataset.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
print('ok')
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(15, activation='softmax')))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
history = model.fit(training_set, labels_train, epochs=1, validation_data=(validation_set, labels_validation))
```

My error: Error when checking target: expected activation 1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (800, 7)

Edit:

I tried an other version, with encoder decoder, which not works for the moment:

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, TimeDistributed, Flatten



# Define an input sequence and process it.
# Input layer of the encoder :
encoder_input = Input(shape=(final_dataset.shape[1], final_dataset.shape[2]))

# Hidden layers of the encoder :
encoder_LSTM = LSTM(120, input_shape=(final_dataset.shape[1], final_dataset.shape[2]), return_sequences=True)(encoder_input)

# Output layer of the encoder :
encoder_LSTM2_layer = LSTM(120, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_LSTM2_layer(encoder_LSTM)

# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]


# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
# Input layer of the decoder :
decoder_input = Input(shape=(6,))

# Hidden layers of the decoder :


decoder_LSTM_layer = LSTM(120, input_shape=(6,), return_sequences=True)
decoder_LSTM = decoder_LSTM_layer(decoder_input, initial_state = encoder_states)

decoder_LSTM_2_layer = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_LSTM_2,_,_ = decoder_LSTM_2_layer(decoder_LSTM)

# Output layer of the decoder :
decoder_dense = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_LSTM_2)


# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_input, decoder_input], decoder_outputs)

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([final_dataset,
               labels_train[:,:6]],
               labels_train[:,6])
```

Comment: Since the second version does not work also, I think that the name TimeDistributed in the question name is misleading